# Using nested If statement in Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

I'm trying to use field calculator to assign values to a new field I created. I wan't to assign the value from the first field unless that field is empty, if it is empty use field 2, if that is empty use field 3. Here is what I have thus far. I feel it is way off but not sure where to go from here.

New_Size: My new field

wmDeviceEq: First field to check for new field name

wmDevice_4: Second ""

wmDevice_5: Third ""

[image: Field_Calculator_Image]

Comment: What happens? Please, update the question with relevant information.

Comment: Nothing happens, I get an error for syntax on second line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the codeblock, you can only use parameters, not field names. You'll need to create parameters for each of your field names, like so:

```py
def Reclass(f1, f2, f3):
    New_size = f1 # this doesn't actually do anything
    if f1 == '':
        return f2
    elif f2 == ''
        return f3
    else: # is this cutoff?
        return f1 # New_size maybe?
```

and then

```py
Reclass(!wmDeviceEq!, !wmDevice_4!, !wmDevice_5!)
```

What if `f3` (`wmDevice_5`) is empty? Not sure if your picture is showing a cuttoff `else` statement.

Are the values in the fields actually empty strings? Shapefiles store a single space `" "` and feature classes in a geodatabase typically use `<Null>`, which in Python would be `None`.

If the fields are actually empty strings and only one field will ever have data, you don't need the code-block at all.

```py
"".join((!wmDeviceEq!, !wmDevice_4!, !wmDevice_5!))
```

As an aside, a nested `if` statement would be something like this:

```py
if result > 10:
    print("Greater than 10")
    if result < 100:
        print("and less than 100")
    else:
        print("It's big...")
else:
    print("Too small!")
```

Comment: "If the fields are actually empty strings and only one field will ever have data, you don't need the code-block at all.

"".join((!wmDeviceEq!, !wmDevice_4!, !wmDevice_5!))
"  I think what you gave me at the beggining will get me to what I was needing. but could you explane this join a little more?  Also, if all three of the fields are empty then the new column(New_Size) needs to be left empty as well, or assign some kind of filler such as "none" or "unassigned" maybe.

Comment: @JeffC, `"".join()` concatenates a list of strings with the the delimiter, which in this case, is an empty string. If you wanted a comma, say, it'd be `",".join()`

Answer (score 0):

@Paul

I edited the code and came up with this

```
def Reclass( ph1, ph2, ph3 ):
  New_Size = ph1
  if ph1 == ' ':
      return ph2
  elif ph2 == ' ':
      return ph3
  elif ph3 == ' ':
      print ("NULL")
```

and then

Reclass(!wmDeviceEq!, !wmDevice_4!, !wmDevice_5!)

When it runs my new field pulls values from only ph2...
[image]
Also not sure about that final elif. it's meant to fill a space that has no value to pull, with a "Null".

I tried the "".join() function but it places spaces every time it moves to the next field, like so.
[image]

Won't work  unless there is a way to remove those spaces before the values in the New_Size field.

Comment: This should probably be a new question or an edit to the original. You can remove extra spaces by adding `.strip()` so it'd be something like `"".join((!wmDeviceEq!, !wmDevice_4!, !wmDevice_5!)).strip()`

Comment: Will that also remove the spaces within the text in each field? I have to have the spaces that exist within "35-HR OCR".

Comment: the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) are great.